# Why would this code be used to get how many enum members there are?

Tags: c++, enums

Whilst looking at the [High Integrity C++ Coding Standard](http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/7-2-2-initialize-none-the-first-only-or-all-enumerators-in-an-enumeration/), I came across the following,

```
# include <cstdint>
// Compliant
enum Team : int32_t {
    Anna
    , Bob
    , Joe
    , John
    , Sandra
    , Tim
    , Team_First = Anna
    , Team_Last = Tim
    , Team_Size
};
int32_t performance [ Team_Size ];
```

I don't understand why Team_Size would come after Team_First and Team_Last. If used this way, then the Team_Size would be 2 higher than actual people exist. I've asked for clarification on the site, but, while waiting, wondered if anyone here had any clues.

Comment: See those assignments for `Team_First` and `Team_Last`?

Comment: Just compile the code, you will see that it works correctly. Alternatively, assign values manually according to the enum rules if you don't believe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `C++` standard `[dcl.enum]/2`:

> ... If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator by one.

`Team_Last` is initialized to the value of `Tim`. `Team_Size == Team_Last+1 == Tim+1`, which is the number of elements in the enumerator, excluding the sentry elements (since enum values start at `0`).

Comment: Yes, that was the bit of the standard I had in mind. But it didn't register with me that because Team_First and Team_Last were being assigned to they wouldn't simply get the previous value + 1.